# Expect script: How to expect a literal * character instead of * as glob or regex character

Tags: expect, tcl

I have an expect script that spawns a connection to hunspell to check the spelling of a word. Unfortunately, if the word is in the dictionary, hunspell simply sends back a *. How can I tell expect to interpret it as a character instead of as "anything?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two layers: the pattern matcher, and TCL. The trick is to backslash a backslash so the subsequent star isn't special after it works its way down through the layers involved.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#spawn echo "cat"
spawn echo "*"
expect {
    "cat" { set gots "dog" }
    "\\*" { set gots "star" }
}

puts $gots
```

Comment: Many thanks. As it turns out, the script was not waiting correctly for a complete reply before moving on to the next item in the loop, then matching the wrong reply from the spawned process. When I saw the mismatches (successes that should have been failures), I mistakenly thought \\* wasn't escaping as I wanted it to. As it turned out, I needed to add another expect statement to wait for some carriage returns from the spawned process before the loop was allowed to continue. Again, thanks for the prompt reply!